# ValueError: year 0 is out of range seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am struggling to plot a simple time series with seaborn and can't understand why this hasn't work. My dataframe `time_series` give daily data for patients from 2015 to 2019 and also has a `datetime` index.It looks as such:

```
            patients
Date                
2015-01-04        49
2015-01-05        51
2015-01-06        48
2015-01-07        30
2015-01-08        27
```

I am trying to build a scatter plot, however upon building it, it starts at 2000 and therefore all the data points are to the right of the graph. I tried to counter this by setting an `xlim` but am receiving a strange error. My code is as such:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.scatterplot(x=time_series.index, y=time_series['patients'])
plt.xlim(2015,2019)
```

This is the error which I don't understand as I have no year '0':

```
ValueError: year 0 is out of range
```

Can anyone help me out here. Many Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["ValueError: year is out of range" when attempting to use matplotlib pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742955/valueerror-year-is-out-of-range-when-attempting-to-use-matplotlib-pyplot)

Comment: It seems that your x is the index value which ranges from 0 to n. The x range you possibly want is for time_series.Date. Therefore, providing the limits is not working as it is looking from 0 to n and you provide it a range from 2015 to 2019

Comment: @WasifHasan `AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'` Receive this error when attempting that method.

Comment: @Phyast10 This won't work as there is no `Date` column, it is the index

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney where are these values coming from?

Answer (score 1):

- The issue seems to be that the `datetime` information from the `df.index` is converted to a datetime ordinal representation for the plot `locs`.
- If you use `locs, labels = plt.xticks()`, comment out `plt.xlim` and print `locs`, you will see they are `array([729390.00000485, 730120.00000485, 730851.00000485, 731581.00000485, 732312.00000485, 733042.00000485, 733773.00000485, 734503.00000485, 735234.00000485, 735964.00000485])`. So when you set `plt.xlim(2015, 2019)` you are not in the range of the `locs` being plotted. The years are just labels.
- Given your sample dataframe with the a datetime index

```py
from datetime import date, datetime

# determine ordinal value for desired date range
print(date.toordinal(datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0)))
>>>735599
print(date.toordinal(datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0)))
>>>737060

chart = sns.scatterplot(x=df.index, y=df['patients'])
plt.xlim(735599, 737060)

plt.setp(chart.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

[image]